# Cannot access Enum in Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular2-template

My purpose is use the enum to read a array's property. This code gives me error:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let elem of list">
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12  ui-lg-12 ui-xl-12">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-sm-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-3 ui-xl-3">
      <input type="text" pInputText value="{{elem[StudentEnum.name] }}" name="student_name" />
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

`StudentEnum` is a enum class, but if i put in the template it doesn't work. What is the correct method to read array properties and values using a enum in a template?

```
{{ elem[StudentEnum.name] }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The variables referenced using the interpolation syntax `{{ }}` is scoped within the corresponding component's class. It has no access to variable like `StudentEnum` that's defined outside this class' scope.

#### Option 1: Local member variable

You could create a local member variable to hold the enum. Here is an illustration:

```js
import { StudentEnum } from './model/student.enum.ts';

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public studentEnum = StudentEnum;  // <-- assign the enum to a member variable

  ...
}
```

```html
<!-- Notice the small `s` in `studentEnum`. It's referring to the member variable -->

<input type="text" pInputText value="{{elem[studentEnum.name] }}" name="student_name"/>
```

#### Option 2: Pipe

If you do not wish to create a local member variable for each component where the enum is used, you could create a pipe to return the corresponding value.

For example

**student.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentEnum } from './model/student.enum.ts';

@Pipe({
  name: 'student',
  pure: true,
})
export class StudentPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    return StudentEnum[value];
  }
}
```

And use it in the template

```html
<input type="text" pInputText value="{{elem['name' | student] }}" name="student_name"/>
```